# I got an error " ScriptResourceMapping in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I have this error: "WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive)" I already put this in my web.config file:

```
<appSettings>
      <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
```

but still doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: True. I found the answer on that question.. 3 answers below that one that is supposed to be the right one! Thank you for the tip! I already answer my question with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something that I found in another question after some suggestion.
For my case, to fix this problem on specific page need to set some validation settings when page loading. Write code below in Page_Load() method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ValidationSettings.UnobtrusiveValidationMode = UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;
    }
```